# Como Compilar Aplicativo Android API 19?

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Tenho um aplicativo aqui que é um pouco antigo e eu preciso fazer a compilação dele com a API 19. Mas quando fui tentar subir na Google Play, fui alertado que meu aplicativo deveria ser pelo menos da API 26 (Android 8.0).

Mas eu preciso compilar com a API 19 por causa das bibliotecas que o aplicativo usa.

Estava lendo sobre o **compileSdkVersion**, mas eu tenho pouca experiência nessa área de build de aplicativos.

Como posso proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro da Play Store provavelmente indicava que o seu aplicativo deve suportar a API 26, o que significa que seus `compileSdkVersion` e `targetSdkVersion` devem ter valor igual ou superior a 26. Na prática, o primeiro atributo indica quais funcionalidades o mesmo pode utilizar, de modo que você receba erros de compilação ao tentar, por exemplo, utilizar um método não suportado; e o segundo é uma indicação de que o aplicativo suporta a versão informada. Esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694276/3237900) (em inglês) tem mais informações.

Tendo isso esclarecido, minha sugestão é atualizar o Android Studio para uma versão superior a 3.0; e atualizar o `compileSdkVersion` e `targetSdkVersion` do app para as versões mais recentes possíveis (>=26) e sincronizar o Gradle. Durante a mudança das versões você provavelmente terá de atualizar outras dependências, como o Gradle Build Tools e demais bibliotecas. Uma dica é manter as dependências do Android Support em sua versão 27, pois na versão seguinte são introduzidas mudanças relacionadas ao AndroidX que você provavelmente não vai querer utilizar (é necessário converter a aplicação pois todos os componentes visuais de suporte são movidos para outros pacotes).